# Get legend names and colors from ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I would like to pull the legend data from a `ggplot2`. I've tried the function `layer_data()`, but this can run slow as I'm trying to pull the data from some large maps made in `ggplot2`. Is there a function to pull just the unique legend characteristics?

I'm going to create some new legends in Inkscape using the hex colors and labels from maps.

My input object is a ggplot2 object, and my desired output is a dataframe or two vectors that contain the listed items in the legend and their corresponding hex colors.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear, please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific in what's unclear? I'm having difficulting creating a reproducible example as I don't have an error that I'm trying to overcome.

Comment: What's your input and wanted output?

Comment: Thanks, see the edits. I have a series of ggplot2 objects and would like to get a dataframe or list out that specifies colors and labels.